# User can tab to a UITextField that has user interaction disabled

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have disabled user interaction in a UITextField:

```
textField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

and still (at least in the simulator) the user can tab to that field and enter data. To work around this, I've had to do the following in my UITextFieldDelegate:

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    // This seems really odd.
    return isUserInteractionEnabled
}
```

A bug in the UITextField? Or behavior as intended? (This is with iOS 11.4 running under Xcode 9.4.1.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting textField.enabled = false.

This is a property of UIControl interface on UIView.

From UIControl.h comment: if NO, ignores touch events and subclasses may draw differently.